# Proof for Geometric Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, foundations

I have been reading Ian Stewart's *Foundations of Mathematics* and would greatly appreciate help with the following question.

$s_n = a + ar + ... a{r^n}$

$rs_n = ar + ar^2 + ... a{r^{n+1}}$

$rs_n - s_n = a(r^{n+1}-1) $

Deduce that

$ |s_n - \frac{a}{1-r}| = |\frac{r^{n+1}}{1-r}| . $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factorize $s_n$ out:
$$s_n(r-1)=a(r^{n+1}-1)$$
Divided by $r-1$:
$$s_n=\frac{a(r^{n+1}-1)}{r-1}$$
Multiply numerator and denominator by $-1$:
$$s_n=\frac{a(1-r^{n+1})}{1-r}$$

Edit: 
$$s_n-\frac{a}{1-r}=\frac{-ar^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

$$\left|s_n-\frac{a}{1-r}\right|=\left|\frac{-ar^{n+1}}{1-r}\right|=\left|\frac{ar^{n+1}}{1-r}\right|$$

Remark:

There was a mistake in the formula, $a$ should be present at the RHS of the formula.

Example:

let $a=2$, $r=\frac12$,$n=1$, We have $$s_1=2+1=3$$
$$\left|s_1-\frac{a}{1-r}\right|=\left|3-\frac{2}{1/2}\right|=\left|3-4\right|=1$$

$$\left|\frac{r^2}{1-r}\right|=\frac{1/4}{1/2}=\frac12$$

$$\left|\frac{ar^2}{1-r}\right|=1$$

Comment: Thank you, @Siong Thye Goh. My mistake was trying to derive everything algebraically. I had your formula above, but kept pushing forward. Now I see that I just had to plug it in and subtract to complete the proof. Thanks again.

Comment: @ddcastrodd Heh, few steps problem.  No need for pushing any further.  (though I guess you could derive some useful things by pushing further...as neat things to remember)

Comment: Wait a second, guys. I was checking my work this morning.

Comment: Please see above edit.

Comment: edited to complete the work. Are you able to follow the step?

Comment: What I cannot understand is how to cancel out "a" in the numerator?

Comment: Good catch, The $a$ is indeed there.

Comment: Ah, so my book does have a misprint. I was going crazy searching for the problem.